# Reference to a pointer to a constant int value. C++

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

While studying constants, pointers and references, I encountered the following problem. The following code throws an error: `cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘const int*&’ to an rvalue of type ‘const int*’`.

```
int* numPtr = new int(5);
const int*& numPtrRef = numPtr;
```

But the following 2 blocks of code work without errors.

```
int* numPtr = new int(5);
const int* const& numPtrRef = numPtr;
```

```
const int* numPtr = new int(5);
const int*& numPtrRef = numPtr;
```

I don't understand why this is happening. It seems like non-const objects can be assigned to const objects, but for some reason the error seems to say the opposite. Please help me figure this out.

I do not have any practical goal, I want to understand the c ++ language, so I'm wondering why this code gives an error.

Comment: https://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html Also note that in these examples you never assign anything. You are initializing some objects and binding some references.

Comment: *"I want to understand the c ++ language..."* That is why you should consult a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). These basic things are explained in any such beginner c++ book. **Stackoverflow is not an "introduction to C++"**. That is, in addition to trial and error, a good c++ book should also be used.

Answer (score 1):

If first example worked then it could lead to mind-boggling bugs:

```
int * numPtr{};
const int * & numPtrRef = numPtr; // assume this is working
const int x{42};
numPtrRef = &x;
// now numPtr also points to const x
*numPtr = 24; // OOPS!
```

Therefore language does not permit binding a reference to object of type "mutable pointer to immutable object" to an object of type "mutable pointer to mutable object".

No such problems happen in case of examples 2 and 3.

Answer (score 0):

Why (3) works should be obvious.

(2) works because `numPtrRef`, being a reference to `const` (to const pointer to const int), can bind to temporaries. When you initialize it with `int *` (which is not the type it wants, `const int *`), a temporary pointer with the right type is created from the original pointer, and the reference is initialized to point to the temporary (whose lifetime is then [extended](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary) to match the lifetime of the reference).

(1) doesn't work, because references to non-const types can't bind to temporaries.

It can be made to work by casting the original pointer to a reference to the correct type:

```
const int *& numPtrRef = const_cast<const int *&>(numPtr);
```

`const_cast` essentially acts as `reinterpret_cast` here, with a little more protection.

Normally this would be a [strict aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/98650/2752075) violation, but there's an exception to this rule ([1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#basic.lval-11), [2](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr#def:similar_types)) permitting a mismatch in `const`ness.